# Can someone please explain flag weight or link me to the appropriate page?

Tags: discussion, support, profile-page, flag-weight

This may be a more StackExchange-centric question rather than one specific to Android.SE, but I'd like to understand that metric on my profile page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is, basically, a measure of how trustworthy your "flags" are. That is, what priority posts get when you flag them for moderator attention. The higher the number, the greater weight your flags are given.

[FAQ: What is 'flag weight'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80170/what-is-flag-weight)

Comment: Thanks, Al.  Out of curiosity, is there an upper maximum to this measure?

Comment: Yes, 750. But it's an asymptotic value. The closer you get to that value the harder it is to reach. Up to weight 500 it's a linear graph.

Comment: Very cool, thanks again!

Comment: AFAIK, all this does is help sort our moderator queues.  Those with higher weights are sorted higher in our queue than those with lower weights.

Comment: @BryanDenny: Yes, that's correct, although if someone's flag weight goes to 0 they'll be blocked from flagging.

Comment: Thanks @Al, I didn't know about the 0 part

Comment: @Bryan: Surprised me too. I don't know if someone can get off of zero and be able to flag ever again.